# Only first two media queries works in CSS. Rest is being ignored

Tags: html, css, mobile, media, responsive

I'm sure there is a really simple solution to my problem.

I have tree media queries, but only the first two works. The 800px one is simply being ignored when viewed on phone.

```css
div {
  color: yellow;
  font-size: 50px;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  div {
    color: red;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  div {
    color: green;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  div {
    color: purple;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Hello</div>
```

Comment: Works fine http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LxJEry

Comment: You could also target mobile first and then customize out from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the  meta tag to your html with initial-scale set to 1.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the code works fine in on desktop if just resizing the browser window, but does not work using chrome to emulate screen size - so this may be a problem with the emulator. You'd have to load the page onto a mobile device or try a couple different emulators to be sure.